# Unexpected behavior of 'cmake -E compare_files' in add_test()

Tags: cmake, ctest

I'm attempting to compare code output with reference text using CTest (`add_test()`) and I'm getting some strange results which makes me think I'm not using `cmake -E compare_files` correctly. The documentation and examples are a bit thin and I haven't found an example similar to what I'm trying to do.

Backstory: I'm recovering some creaky ancient FORTRAN code which expects input via `stdin` and writes output to `stdout`. Knowing that I/O redirection in `add_test()` is discouraged/impossible, I use `add_custom_command()` as a `POST_BUILD` action on the executable target to run the code and redirect output. That works as expected - no problems there.

I then set up two tests resembling:

```cmake
# Compare fresh output and known different example output
add_test(NAME C1_bad
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E compare_files --ignore-eol C1.OUT C1_bad.OUT
    CONFIGURATIONS Debug Release ""
    WORKING_DIR "${MY_TEST_DIR}"
)

# Compare fresh output and known identical example output
add_test(NAME C1_ok
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E compare_files --ignore-eol C1.OUT C1_ok.OUT
    CONFIGURATIONS Debug Release ""
    WORKING_DIR "${MY_TEST_DIR}"
)
```

Three files are compared here:

- `${MY_TEST_DIR}/C1.OUT` is generated by the post-build custom command - this is fresh output.
- `${MY_TEST_DIR}/C1_bad.OUT` is copied from the source tree and is different from `C1.OUT`.
- `${MY_TEST_DIR}/C1_ok.OUT` is copied from the source tree and is binary identical to `C1.OUT` (confirmed by inspection and MD5 checksum).

Unexpectedly, both tests fail, not just the first one. Running `cmake -E compare_files` from the command line against each pair of files gives expected results - comparing `C1_bad.OUT` and `C1.OUT` fails (i.e. complains that the files are different) but comparing `C1_ok.OUT` and `C1.OUT` succeeds (returns no output; silence implies success).

My thought is that `cmake -E compare_files` does not return status codes expected by CTest (0 to pass, non-zero to fail) or is otherwise not intended for use with CTest. This is with version 3.18.1 on Windows if that matters; I get the same behavior with 3.18.1 on Linux. I don't want to chase down or write my own cross-platform diff utility if CMake has one already built in but it's not clear from everything I've read whether this is an expected or workable use of `compare_files` - any hints on what I should try next?